# Passing switches ( eg -IncludeManagementTools) to Install-WindowsFeature as variables

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using this as a way of finally getting around to using Stackoverflow properly!

I'm trying to run the following line as part of a larger script:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```

WHich obviously works on it's own, but not when I try and pass "-IncludeManagementTools" as part of a variable.

I'm reading in the list of features to install as part of a text file, and some of these have option parameters like -IncludeManagementTools .  Passing the first part "Web-Server" works fine, passing the second part doesn't, unless typed in directly to the console, ie

```
    $var="Web-Server"        
    Install-WindowsFeature $var -IncludeManagementTools
```

Full current code is below;  I've tried splitting on the variable as well as what is below, and using Switch statements rather than if loops, but the optional parameter always gets misinterpreted as the name of the feature to install eg:

```
    $currentline = "Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools"
    Install-WindowsFeature $currentline.Split(" ")[0]
```

Works, but

```
    $currentline = "Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools"
    Install-WindowsFeature $currentline.Split(" ")[0] $currentline.split(" ")[1]
```

Fails.  ANy help greatly appreciated!

Full code:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$ConfigFilePath
)

$featurelist = Import-Csv $ConfigFilePath

# Install requested features
$featurelist | % {
    # The install commands have some optional switches which could be in the input file
    # to avoid an error reading in the Install-* commands, split on " " and feed into the command as seperate strings
    If ( $_.feature -contains " " ) {
        If ( $_.feature -eq "-IncludeManagementTools") {Install-WindowsFeature -Name "($_.feature.Split(" ")[0]) -IncludeManagementTools"}
        Else {}
        If ( $_.feature -eq "-IncludeAllSubFeature") { Install-WindowsFeature -Name "($_.feature.Split(" ")[0]) -IncludeAllSubfeature" }
        Else {}
        }
    Else {
        Install-WindowsFeature -Name $_.feature
    }
}

$installed = @()

# Check installs work
$featurelist | % {
    # The install commands have some optional switches which could be in the input file
    # to avoid an error reading in the Get-* commands, remove anything that comes after a space (ie effectively removing optional switches)
    $installed += Get-WindowsFeature -Name $_.feature.Split(" ")[0]
    }

$missing = $installed | ? { $_.Installed -eq $false }

If (!($missing)) {
    Write-Host "All requested features installed ok." -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
}
Else {
    Write-Host "Some features requested weren't installed.  They will be outputted below." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Red
    $missing
}
```

Comment: I think I'd use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for this, using a bit of logic to construct the hashtable with the params you want.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually used the technique below of specifying the subfeatures, but this is a useful thought process for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```

Run the following

```
Get-WindowsFeature
```

It should show all windows features installed. Whatever is included in the 'Include Management Tools' switch is broken down and has it's own feature Name.  So everything can be installed with 'Install-WindowsFeature -Name xxx'

Comment: I think this is really elegant solution, although running the Get-* doesn't actually work, but I found it with a wildcard search:

PS C:\Users\manniisup> Get-WindowsFeature *tools*

Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
    [X] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools                 Installed

Comment: It is Get-WindowsFeature <x>, not Get-x, so I would not downvote my original response because you misunderstood it.

Comment: Hi Erik, I didn't meant to downvote, sorry - new to Stack, i did understand the answer (its a star not an x)!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, more of a recommendation to change how you've structured your setup to something that's more explicit and more maintainable.

It looks to me like you'd benefit from using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6).  It lets you use a hashtable to hold the parameters for a command, which can make dynamic parameters a bit easier.

```
$WindowsFeatureParameters = @{
    Name = 'Web-Server'
    IncludeManagementTools = $true
}
Install-WindowsFeature @WindowsFeatureParameters
```

I would also change your CSV file to have a different column for each parameter.  Imagine something like:

```
FeatureName,IncludeManagementTools,IncludeAllSubFeature
Web-Server,Yes,No
```

Now you can specify:

```
$FeatureList = Import-Csv $ConfigFilePath 
foreach ($Feature in $FeatureList) {
    $WindowsFeatureParameters = @{
        Name = 'Web-Server'
        IncludeManagementTools = ($Feature.IncludeManagementTools -eq 'Yes')
        IncludeAllSubFeature= ($Feature.IncludeAllSubFeature -eq 'Yes')
    }
    Install-WindowsFeature @WindowsFeatureParameters
}

$Installed = foreach ($Feature in $FeatureList) {
    Get-WindowsFeature -Name $Feature.FeatureName
}

$Missing = $Installed | Where-Object Installed -eq $false
```

---

Alternately, you can specify a variable with a switch to control it's value:

```
# Install with management tools
$ManagementTools = $true
Install-WindowsFeature 'Web-Server' -IncludeManagementTools:$ManagementTools

# Install without management tools
$ManagementTools = $false
Install-WindowsFeature 'Web-Server' -IncludeManagementTools:$ManagementTools
```

Obviously, `$ManagementTools` could be set by any boolean test.

Comment: I agree this is more elegant solution - but have you tried it to see if it doesn't fall foul of the issue I described?